# Calculating point on sphere using inverse projection

Tags: geometry

The diagram below represents the top-down view of a sphere at position (0,0,0). I have a point within the sphere (x,y,z). The arrows represent the facing direction. I need to project (x,y,z) in the inverse of the facing direction onto the sphere to get point (A).

[image: Sphere]

I know x,y,z and I know the facing direction. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use unit vector $\hat{n} = (x_n, y_n, z_n)$ for the facing direction (the big black arrow). Although its length is not critical, having it be $1$ (thus unit vector) makes the math simpler.

You have a sphere of radius $r$ centered at origin. This means that point $\vec{s}$ is on the surface, if and only if
$$\vec{s} \cdot \vec{s} = r^2$$

You have a point $\vec{p} = (x, y, z)$ inside the sphere. We need to move it by $t$ ($t \ge 0$) opposite to the facing direction $\hat{n}$:
$$\vec{p}' = \vec{p} - t \hat{n}$$
The moved point is on the surface when
$$\vec{p}' \cdot \vec{p}' = r^2$$
Substituting $\vec{p}'$ we get
$$\left( \vec{p} - t \hat{n} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{p} - t \hat{n} \right) = r^2$$
If we apply $\hat{n}\cdot\hat{n} = x_n^2+y_n^2+z_n^2 = 1$, the above expands and simplifies to
$$t^2 + (-2 x x_n - 2 y y_n - 2 z z_n ) t + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - r^2 = 0$$
which is easy to solve for $t$:
$$t = x x_n + y y_n + z z_n \pm \sqrt{ (x x_n + y y_n + z z_n)^2 + r^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2}$$
Because of how we defined the projection, a positive $t$ projects the point to the closer hemisphere of the sphere, and a negative $t$ to the further hemisphere; thus, we are interested in the positive (larger) real $t$:
$$t = x x_n + y y_n + z z_n + \sqrt{ (x x_n + y y_n + z z_n)^2 + r^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2}$$
The projected point itself, $\vec{p}' = (x', y', z')$ is
$$\vec{p}' = \vec{p} - t\hat{n} = (x - t x_n, y - t y_n, z - t z_n)$$